# Trying to return scraped html tags in Flask-restful throwing error, is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, api, flask, flask-restful

Error looks like below
[image]

```
 soup2=BeautifulSoup(marks.content,'html.parser')      
 markstable=soup2.find('table')
 return {'marksheet':markstable}
```

Writing above part of codes,in the marstable variable it has the html markuptags being fetched from the scrapped content of website. Am returning it directly to the end points for the client to receive it.

Is it the wrong way of sending. How should I be sending it instead. 
I am making the rest api using flask and flask_restful

Answer (score 0):

Check the type on `markstable`.  I believe BS .find method returns a dict, not a string, so you will need to serialize it to json prior to returning.

try adding jsonify to your imports from flask and then

`return jsonify(markstable= markstable)`

Comment: Yea, imported jsonify and than used jsonify for the masrkstable but still has the same errors

Comment: I tried this too but same problem, markstable = json.dumps(markstable)
        return {'marksheet':markstable}

Comment: Its a result from the bs4 beautifulsoup scraped content. Trying to check the  vaiable types says TypeError: <class 'bs4.element.Tag'> is not JSON serializable

Comment: Take a look here.  https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-the-tree
You will not be able to simply dump that class into a JSON string and return it.  Maybe you want to get the contents?  If the client is going to receive it and do more parsing, then perhaps you can use something like pickle to persist it.  Otherwise I think you will need to do more work to get the contents of the table so it can be serialized into something json.dumps can understand